# Order by asc Sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sql order by asc query and i have to order varchar field which contains integer value(I can't change the data type to int as there is already lots of data in that table changing may lose data). Result of the sorting is as following

```
1
2
3
.
.
8
9
10
101
102
103
.
.
109
11
110
111
.
.
119
12
```

Result should be

```
1
2
3
.
.
8
9
10
11
12
```

query is

```
      dbAccess.execute("SELECT [id],[SNo],LetterSNO,[SubjectOfLetter],[FrmWhere],[WhomTosend],
(Cast(Day(DateOfRecieve) as Varchar(3))+'/'+Cast(Month(DateOfRecieve) as Varchar(2))+'/'+Cast(Year(DateOfRecieve) as Varchar(4))) as DateOfRecieve ,[Remarks] ,[User_IPAddress], 
(Cast(Day(DateOfSending) as Varchar(3))+'/'+Cast(Month(DateOfSending) as Varchar(2))+'/'+Cast(Year(DateOfSending) as Varchar(4))) as DateOfSending
 FROM [MpscdrcTESTING].[dbo].[tbl_PostalEntry] 
where DateOfRecieve between '" + TextBox1.Text.Trim() + "' and  '" + TextBox2.Text.Trim() + "' order by SNo asc";
```

please help

Comment: Your code is susceptible to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack.

Comment: If your column really only contains integer values, you can ***easily*** change the data type! And you **really should!**

Comment: yes @jamiec i should use stored procedure.. thanks

Comment: Yes @marc_s it contains only integer values but when i am trying to change datatype it is giving warning of losing data

Comment: Yes - it's giving a warning, since there *could* be a data loss ***if*** some of your values weren't numeric..... (or the if string were too long and thus contains a number that's too big to fit into an `INT`). Try this: (1) back up your existing database, (2) restore it under a different name, (3) try the conversion of that column to `INT` in that new copy of the database. Most likely, it'll **just work** ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ORDER BY CAST(sNO as INT)
```